# How should Nikon be pronounced?

Tags: nikon

In the US/Canada, I've heard Nikon pronounced as ***nye-con***, as in *n-eye-con*.

When I was in Southeast Asia, I heard it pronounced as ***knee-con***. I'm assuming everywhere else in the world would pronounce it this way as well.

**Is there a correct or universal way of pronouncing "Nikon"?** I got some funny looks when I pronounced it as the former during my stay in SE Asia.

Comment: See also: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1452/can-i-trust-the-quality-of-japanese-to-english-translation-sites

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a regional thing - there is no universal way *per se*. In the UK most people pronounce it *nick-on*.

Considering Nikon is Japanese, however, and in Japan it's pronounced *knee-con*, one could argue that that is the 'correct' pronunciation. The Wikipedia article on Nikon gives the following pronunciation guide, which is very Japanese, with a palatised n at the end:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Nikon.ogg

Comment: I don't agree that this is a regional thing. It is just wrong Americanese. Just as they butchered IKEA, SUBARU and more.

Comment: @ysap: Erm... how can it be "wrong"? Americans don't speak Japanese -- We speak English. Expecting a word to be translated faithfully in spelling as well as pronunciation is unrealistic whenever a word is borrowed across languages. English usually borrows the spelling but it rarely borrows pronunciation without at least some anglicizing .

Comment: +1 for using _per_se_ (and in italics!  :)  (oh, also, a great answer ;)

Comment: @ysap: this is absolutely a regional thing: it's pronounced differently in different regions. Americans pronounce I in such a position _eye_ (v-eye-tamin), Brits pronounce it _ih_ (vitt-amin), and East Asians pronounce it _ee_, as in the Japanese for Japan _nihon/nee-hon_. @AJ Finch: sprinkling Latin into your posts makes you sound clever :D

Comment: @Billy ONeal Americans speak (and spell) American English, not English :)

Comment: @Jam: There's little difference between the two when we're comparing English and Japanese. More to the point "English English" and "American English" are the same language -- we might generally use different words and pronounce some things a bit differently, but I can go to England and be understood just fine, just as an Englishman can come to the US and be understood just fine.

Comment: @ysap It may be butchered, but the "American" pronunciation has been accepted by Nikon USA. See their [TV ads](http://ashton.nikonusa.com/COOLPIX/nikon-ads.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

I live and work in Japan as a translator and am fully bilingual, with a number of bilingual camera geeks in my social circle (some of whom actually work for Nikon).

I can confirm that there is no "correct" way to pronounce the word. Bilinguals when speaking Japanese pronounce it ニコン, which cannot be correctly replicated with English phonemes (the i is like an "ee" sound but shorter, the o is an "oh" sound but shorter, and the final n sound just doesn't exist in English). When speaking English, we pronounce it as Nigh-kon when speaking North American English and Nick-on when speaking British English.

In conversations with North American bilinguals, many voice the opinion that it sounds pretentious to pronounce it Nick rather than Nike when speaking with a North American accent. But that's a matter of personal taste, not correctness.

Answer (score 0):

In Japanese, the letter i (and character for it) is pronounced "ee" and it is a Jawpawneese word so, therefore, it is Neekawn just as a Toyota Celica is properly said Celica.